# RecyclerView's item doesn't resize when other item is removed

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I've got a problem with view resizing in `RecyclerView`.

Consider scenario presented on the image below. Before removing an item we've got 3 items, two of them have the same size and one (the first one) is a little bit bigger.

When the first item is removed, `RecyclerView` reuses its view. Now the second item becomes the first one, but the view still got the same height. Notice the empty space marked with light red color.

I've tried everything to force re-measure of the view but nothing seems to work. Is there any possibility to resize it?

[image]